# how to paste a command to vim to execute

Tags: vim, paste

When running bash in either a Linux Terminal window or from Windows via ssh in a PuTTY window, I can paste character sequences into it via mouse middle click (in Linux Terminal) or right click or shift/Insert (in PuTTY) and they will be processed just as if I had typed them on the keyboard while the window had focus.

When I run vim in the window, the behaviour is different.
Pasting a vim command string into the window when vim is in normal mode does *not* execute the command as it would if I typed it in.
Instead, it inserts it into the buffer at the current cursor position even though vim stays in normal mode.

Now I understand that this behaviour may spare someone not familiar with vi or vim some surprises.
But I find myself often in a situation where I would like to perform some complex vim command by pasting it from the clipboard or X buffer instead of typing it, especially if I need to run the same command multiple times.

How can I achieve that?

Test case:

Run PuTTY on a Windows machine to open an ssh session to a Linux host.

Run `vim /tmp/test`.

Enter the text `:se ts=16` into the editor buffer.
Type ESC to make sure vim is in normal mode.

Copy the line containing the text `:se ts=16`, including the end of line character, to the Windows clipboard by highlighting it with the mouse.

Right-click into the PuTTY window to paste the Windows clipboard content.

Expected behaviour: vim executes the command `:se ts=16` + ENTER, setting the tabstop width to 16.

Actual behaviour: vim inserts the string `:se ts=16` and a new line into the edit buffer.

Comment: Would pressing `<Esc>:` to put Vim into command line mode before pasting be an option? Double colons will not hurt.

Comment: It works, and is what I currently do, for `ex` mode (colon) commands, but has two drawbacks: one, it requires me to switch to the keyboard while in a mouse workflow, and two, it does not work for `vi` mode (non-colon) commands. For example, pasting `03f-dt-"hp` into the vim window will not replace the text between the third and fourth hyphen in the current line with the content of register h as intended, but insert the string `03f-dt-"hp` at the cursor position. (Yes, I did actually use that kind of stuff with older vi versions that were not as paste-aware as vim. ;-)